# Why does Word open with a different normal.dot if started via COM rather than via Start Menu?

Tags: vba, powershell, ms-word, com, com-interop

When I start Microsoft Word on the Start Menu and then query `Application.NormalTemplate.Path` for the location of the `normal.dotm` file, I get, as expected, `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates`.

However, when I start Word using COM automation in PowerShell:

```
$wrd = new-object -com word.application
$wrd.visible = $true
```

I get a different path when querying the same expression:`C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.Office.Desktop_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalCache\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates`.

Why is that and what can I do in order for the COM invocation to open the same normal.dotm file?

Comment: What version and deployment method of Office is this? For me, both times the normal template is located in the expected standard location (AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates) using a Click-to-run Office 365 Version 1903; also I do not have the Microsoft.Office.Desktop folder in my Packages folder.

Comment: P.S.: Looks like your Office is deployed via the Microsoft Store (or that you have two different deployments of Office on your machine, one via the Store, the other one via the regular Click-to-run deployment). I assume the behavior you observe can by explained by that.

Comment: I installed it from a `.iso` file. I admit I have no idea what *Click-to-run* is nor did I realise there was a *Microsoft Store*.

Comment: Could be that the Store version was preinstalled on your system? Try running `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office 16\winword.exe" /r` to re-register all Word components (change the path to where your winword.exe actually is installed to) and see whether this gives you a different result.

Comment: @dirk I tried that and it didn't change antyhing that would have been noticeable to me.